# spark jdbc edit insert statement

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

Is it possible to inject parameter into spark JDBC insert statement?

I'm using

```
spark.sql("select * from my_table ").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc
```

for saving bulk dataframe to my DB.

In `JdbcUtils` the `insertStatement` is created.

Is it possible ( without creating my own JDBC connections and statements) to add a parameter like "abort on error" into the statement?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the parameter that you wish to add. What is its purpose?

Comment: for example "ABORT ON ERROR DIRECT"  command : "insert into table ... ABORT ON ERROR" ;